# C# Chart Control: Capture Reset Zoom event?

Tags: c#, charts, zooming, reset

I would like to capture the event that occurs when the user clicks a chart with the right mouse button and selects "Reset Zoom" because I have four textboxes in the window that display the current values of the chart border (x1, x2, y1, x2), so I would like to reset these values when the user clicks "Reset Zoom". How can I do that?

Comment: It should not be difficult to deduce that I am using the standard library, i.e. System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.

Comment: There is no special event, I think. Try to use the AxisViewChanging event!